# Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'InventoryUI.newDiamondText'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

```
public class BuyableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float PickUpRadius = 1f;
    public InventoryItemData ItemData;

    private SphereCollider myCollider;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        myCollider = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        myCollider.isTrigger = true;
        myCollider.radius = PickUpRadius;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var inventory = other.transform.GetComponent<InventoryHolder>();
        
        if (!inventory) return;

        if (inventory.InventorySystem.AddToInventory(ItemData, 1))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateDiamondText(PlayerInventory playerInventory)
    {
        InventoryUI.newDiamondText.text = playerInventory.NumberOfDiamonds.ToString();
    }
}
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

> Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'InventoryUI.newDiamondText'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the field (or method or whatever it is) `newDiamondText` isn’t static but you’re trying to call it using the static reference to the class `InventoryUI` rather than via a reference to an *instance* of that class.

If you meant `newDiamondText` to be static — i.e. there’s only one of it ever, not one for each copy of the class — you can solve the problem by marking `newDiamondText` as `static`.

Otherwise, you’ll need to access it via a reference to an instance of `InventoryUI` — e.g. something like (but probably not exactly) this:

```
InventoryUI inventoryInstance = new InventoryUI();
inventoryInstance.newDiamondText.text = playerInventory.NumberOfDiamonds.ToString();
```